# Search multiple columns for multiple values

Tags: r

Very new to R
Have a very large data frame (ie looking to avoid using a loop for efficiency) with many columns. I want to scan multiple columns (ex ss1:ss15) for a vector of characters (ex c(‘9515’,’8231’)). If any of these are true/match I am trying to get a new column in the data frame with value 1 if any in that row are true and 0 if not. I’m stuck on how to even begin going about this...

Comment: `as.integer(Reduce('|', lapply(df1[cols], grepl, pattern = paste(vect, collapse="|"))))` or if it is a fixed match `as.integer(Reduce('|', lapply(df1[cols], '%in%', vect)))`

Comment: amazing, you have saved me so much heartwrenching struggles, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can either use `grep`, by looping through the columns of interest by subsetting the dataset, then `Reduce`ing the `list` of logical `vector`s into a single `logical` vector  and subsequently converting to binary with `as.integer`

```
cols <- paste0('ss', 1:15)
vect <- c(‘9515’,’8231’)
as.integer(Reduce('|', lapply(df1[cols], grepl, pattern = paste(vect, collapse="|"))))
```

---

If the 'vect' elements to be searched are fixed and not substrings, we can also use `%in%`

```
as.integer(Reduce('|', lapply(df1[cols], '%in%', vect)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using `magrittr` and data.tables and allowing to manipulate the intermediary matrix:

```
library ( "magrittr" )
vect = c ( "9515", "8231" )

# Creating the data table
N <- 150
dt1 <- matrix (
    sample ( c ( vect, "other" ), N, prob = c ( .05, .05, .9 ), replace = TRUE ),
    ncol = 15, dimnames = list ( NULL, paste0 ( "ss", 1:15 ))) %>% as.data.table

# Initiatilzing the new column
dt1 [, NewCol := rep ( 0, N / 15 )]

# Define query function
InVect <- function ( x ) x %in% vect

# Querying the data table
dt1 [( apply ( dt1, 1:2, InVect ) %>% which ( arr.ind = TRUE ))[, 1 ] %>%
  unique, NewCol := 1 ]
dt1
```

,and another way looping over `vect` instead (may have pros in some situations):

```
# Initiatilzing the new column
dt1 [, NewCol := rep ( 0, N / 15 )]

# Define query function
RowIDs <- function ( x ) ( which ( dt1 == x, arr.ind = TRUE ))[, 1 ]

# querying the data table
dt1 [ lapply ( vect, RowIDs ) %>% unlist %>% unique, NewCol := 1 ]
```